# django render understanding context_instance

Tags: django

I am reading:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

If I understand correctly context_instance is automatically created from the first parameter (request).

How are these values presented to the view? Does it combine them with the dictionary parameters?

What types of things are normally in the context_instance? (I know it is built from request).

I have also read that template pre processors can add data to context_instance.

I am just trying to understand how I can use context_instance and have been searching and haven't quite found the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template context processors are the *only* things that affect the context in any way from a `render` call. All of these - either the default ones, which add things like `user`, or your own custom ones - simply add elements to the context dictionary.

Comment: Does this get merged with the dictionary that is passed in the render function? How do I access that variables in context_instance from a template?

Comment: Yes it's just merged and they are indistinguishable from any other context elements.